# Create Complementary, Triad, and Monochromatic Color palette from single Hex Color

Tags: javascript, php

What I'm trying to do is create three different color palettes from a single hex/rgb value supplied by a user. The palette will have the complement of the supplied color and then a full palette would be generated after. Ideally I'd be able to have a 5-color palette instead of just a single complementary color. I'll also be creating color palettes for triad, analagous, and monochromatic schemes.

I'm looking to figure out is how to actually create the complement color and then the color palette after. The same goes for the other palette types listed here. I'm open to doing this in Javascript or PHP.

Comment: Speed... Modern browsers can handle such math very easily. I don't know the exact equations, but I don't think they exceed four or five lines of summations.

Comment: Please be specific about what you need help with, code wise.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hex+color+calculation

Comment: @Diodeus check out the question again (it's updated). I'm looking to create a complementary color palette from a color. The conversion of hex to rgb, etc, is the easy part.

Comment: **step 1:** convert hex->rgb **step 2:** convert rgb -> hsl **step 3:** add offset (0-359) to h **step 4:** set css rule using hsl values (you can set a colour using hex, rgb or hsl - browser will convert and store natively as rgb, so if you set as hsl then request this colour back again, you'll get an rgb value) This approach will give you a consistant relationship between the input and output colours on an hsl colour wheel - i.e the angle (h) between the two colours will remain the same. Tinting b&w images is done similarly - i.e not in the rgb colour-space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually wrote a small script which can do much of this, [colorflow.js](https://github.com/ExtPro/colorflow.js).

Say your starting color was red (hex: #ff0000)

1. Complementary color: `colorflow.complement('#ff0000')`
2. Complementary color, palette of 5: `colorflow.complement('#ff0000', 'double')`
3. Triadic: `colorflow.triadic('#ff0000')`
4. Monochromatic: `colorflow.rotational_dispersion('#c0c0c0', 5, 'saturation')`

etc...

Comment: I have tried Monochromatic function but it gives me error (Not Defined error in console).